# How to create an array with values from json

Tags: php, json

I have a json file that contains the forecasted air temperature, hour-by-hour, till the end of the day, and I am gathering those values by doing something like this:

```
 (...)
 // $rawData is the file with json
 $decoded = json_decode($rawData, true); 
 // $total_hours is the number of hours till the end of day
 for($k=0;$k<$total_hours;$k++){
 //get air_temp for each hour till the end of day
 $air_temp[$k]=$decoded['timeseries'][$k]['air_temperature'];
 (...)
```

I get all $air_temp[$k] and everything is fine.
What i need now is to create an array to calculate values like $max, $min and $avg temperatures from all the gathered $air_temp[$k] values.

I could create an array by doing something like this:

```
 $array= [$air_temp[0],$air_temp[1],$air_temp[2],$air_temp[3]]; // echo example [12,10,15,13]
 $max_temp=(max($array)); // echoes 15
 $min_temp=(min($array)); // echoes 10
 (...)
```

but the problem is that [$k] depends on $total_hours that it is not a fixed value, and so this option is useless.

My question is: is there a way to create an array where I can include all the $air_temp[$k] values, for further treatment like calculating max, min and avg values of the array?

Comment: Maybe the new array is not needed and it is enough to do this: `$max_temp = max($air_temp);`?

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I tried it and it gives me max_temp value for the whole period of days and not just for the day I am interested in, but, I am going to work on it and maybe it will be a good starting point to solve my problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I have found to create the array, using foreach.

```
// create array
$hour =date('H');  //current hour
$hours_left= (23-$hour); //hours left till end of the day

$i = 0;
$items = array();
foreach ($air_temp as $temp) {
$items[] = $temp;
if(++$i > $hours_left) break;
}

print_r($items);

echo(min($items));
echo(max($items));
```